# Trying to pass stdin to a main method to evaluate code online

Tags: c#, parameters, stdin, codedom

I am trying to build a web application to evaluate .Net code online (like http://ideone.com/)
I have managed to compile code with CodeDomProvider.
But I don't know how to pass stdin parameters to this function.

If a user writes this code in the textarea of my web application:

```
using System;
public class Test  {

    static void Main()
    {
        String t = "";
        while (t != null){
           t = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(t+"OK");
        }
     }
}
```

I can Compile it with this code
      CompilerInfo[] allCompilerInfo = CodeDomProvider.GetAllCompilerInfo();

```
  //Tell the compiler what language was used
  CodeDomProvider CodeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

  //Set up our compiler options...
  CompilerParameters CompilerOptions = new CompilerParameters();
  var _with1 = CompilerOptions;
   _with1.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
  _with1.GenerateInMemory = true;
  _with1.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;

  //Compile the code that is to be evaluated
  CompilerResults Results = CodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerOptions, strCode);
```

Now I would like to manage generic parameters:

If I pass a sample parameter like this:

53

12

09

I would like the result of the compilation:

53OK

12OK

09OK

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: A web app with a `Main()`?  You say you want to build a web application, yet you are processing stdin which is more for console applications.  Are you sure you don't want a console application?

Comment: A web app where user can enter this code in a textarea (like http://www.ideone.com)

Comment: By stdin parameters do you mean command line arguments? `static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: If a web app, you wouldn't be reading from stdin then nor would you have a Main(), you would just take the text from a TextBox control.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - I think what Toc means is that he has a web page that you type code into and it dynamically compiles it and he wants to know how to pass arguments to the compiled product.

Comment: also you want to look at the args or look at how to use params[]

Comment: @M.Babcock: I know, but he's also talking about redirecting stdin.  I'm just pointing out he's wanting a web app but using console app artifacts.

Comment: @Toc - Can you show the code you are using to launch the compiled application?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what M.Babcock said. I am sorry if I am not clear but I am just beginning to learn programming :/

Comment: I'm not trying to be obstinate, it's just that the two paradigms are completely different, so the answer would depend greatly on if the OP wants to get data from stdin (console) or from the web (in which case Main and command line args are useless).

Comment: @Toc: No worries, so you just want to be able to read code from a web page's text box?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - He already has that. He grabs the code from the web pages text box and compiles it to a command line application. Now it seems he is having trouble figuring out how to pass information to the command line application (executing server side).

Comment: Ah I see, I think I see now.  Sorry, didn't mean to be thick, just didn't fully understand. So, if I interpret right, you want to be able to input the code and the input in two separate check boxes, then feed that input into the code.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, in two separate textareas. I've added the code I use to compile the text of the 1st textarea

Comment: @Toc: Got it, sorry, my mind was down the wrong path at first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I interpret the question, you are asking how to run and pass stdin command line data to an application that was compiled on your web server from code that a user typed into a text box. Avoiding the *serious* security concerns of doing such, what you want to do is launch the application using the System.Diagnostics.Process class, and specify RedirectStandardInput in the StartInfo property.  Start by reading the MSDN docs on the Process class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris, it could be the solution. I will try this. I understand the security concerns and will not release it online.

Comment: What to do with `public class Test  
{

    static void Main()
    {
 Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}`

Comment: @L.B, that's one of many issues that he will have to figure out.